# How would you access the elements of an array that which is transformed from a map in JS?

Tags: arrays, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, maps

Do you know the way to access values of the following array which is turned from a hashmap?

[image]

Having tried all that's possible, my final resort is here!

Following represents the lines of codes that remained at last after trying plethora of ways.

```js
.onSnapshot(documentSnapshot => {


                const { comments } = documentSnapshot.data();


                //getting the values of the map
                const commentsArray = Object.values(comments);
                const commentsNew = Object.values(commentsArray);
                const commentsNew1 = Object.keys(commentsNew);
                const commentsNew2 = Object.values(commentsNew1);
                const commentsNewEntries = Object.entries(commentsArray);

                console.log('Comments from comment component: ', commentsArray);
                console.log('NEW comments from comment component: ', commentsNew);
                console.log('NEWEntries comments from comment component: ', commentsNewEntries);
                // console.log(commentsArray);  
                console.log(typeof commentsArray);
                console.log(commentsArray.length);

                for (const prop in commentsNew) {
                    console.log(prop);

                    //console.log(commentsArray[prop]);

                    const theComment = commentsNew[prop];

                    // const allComments = [];

                    // allComments.push(comment);

                    const { comment, likes } = theComment;


                    console.log(theComment);
                    console.log(comment);
                }
```

This is where I write the document or uploading the comment to the firestore:

```js
 try {
            await firestore()
                .collection('posts')
                .doc(id)
                .update({
                    comments: firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion({
                        //id: id,

                        [firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date())]:
                        {
                            userName: firstName,
                            userImage: userImage,
                            comment: theInput,
                            timestamp: firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date()),
                            liked: false,
                            likes: 0,
                        }


                    }),


                })
```

Yeah, I am trying to access the relevant details from the firestore.

Do you know any way to tackle this?

THANK YOU!

EDIT: Added the code for the comment upload.

Comment: Can you show how you write the document? It is not crystal clear what is the type of the field (or fieldS?).

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Thanks for your interest on this. So I added what you requested. You can check it now